Converting conventional to primitive by hand
I am trying to obtain primitive vectors from conventional ones in my crystal with tetragonal symmetry. I know the conventional $3$-vectors that describe the crystal structure and I can obtain primitive because from the textbook I know it is:

$$\begin{array}{ll}  & \text{Conventional lattice}  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad&\text{Primitive lattice}\\  & \mathbf{a}_1 = (a, \ 0, \
0) & \mathbf{a}_1 = (-a/2, \ a/2, \ c/2) \\ &\mathbf{a}_2 = (0, \ a, \
0) & \mathbf{a}_2 = (a/2, \ -a/2, \ c/2)\\ &\mathbf{a}_3 = (0, \ 0, \
c) & \mathbf{a}_3 = (a/2, \ a/2, \ -c/2)\\ \end{array}$$

Do you have suggestions about how to obtain primitive from conventional in general, and also how to obtain the converter matrix?
I appreciate your help.

In general one would follow the Wigner-Seitz process, no?
